# Let $a_0,a_1...$ be a sequence of real numbers if $a_k \to L$ as $k \to \infty$ then does the series converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

$$S_k:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k+1} - 2a_k+a_{k-1}$$

This looks like a definition proof.

Using linearity we can rewrite this as $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k+1}-2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k-1}$$ Since $a_k$ converges to $L$ then we can say that the sequence of partial sums of each part ($a_{k+1},-2a_k,a_{k-1}$) converges to $L$ and therefore since each partial sum converges then by definition $S_k$ converges to $L$ Does this make sense?

Comment: But the individual sums don’t converge to $L$. Instead, the sequence itself converges to $L$. However, the given partial sums $S_n$ will indeed converge as $n\to \infty$. If you write out $S_n$ for some finite $n$ (say $n=10$) you should be able to intuit a general formula for $S_n$.

Comment: In your definition of $S_n$, there is no $n$ on the right.

Comment: ugh sometimes I submit it without looking thoroughly. That made no sense then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that, whether the sum $\displaystyle\sum a_{k}$ converges is not known.

Rather, 
\begin{align*}
S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k+1}-2a_{k}+a_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k+1}-a_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k-1}-a_{k},
\end{align*}
and apply telescoping twice.

Comment: so then we have$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k+1}-a_k=a_1-lim_{k \to \infty} a_k=a_1-L$ and then $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k-1}-a_k=a_{-1}-lim_{k \to \infty} a_k=a_{-1}-L$

Comment: $a_{0}-L$ for the second one.

Comment: Then we have $a_1 - L - a_0 -L$ and what happens when $a_1-a_0-2L$

Comment: Then this is it, the answer.